# How to select numerical strings(strings which contain numbers only) among many strings in javascript and ignore the rest ones?

Tags: javascript

How to select the numerical value elements and how to ignore the alphabatical elements(in this example "2009-10": "NA", "2010-11": "NA" ).

```js
stateData:[ {"1999-00": "125236",
              "2000-01": "140119",
              "2001-02": "151482",
              "2002-03": "163385",
              "2003-04": "184463",
              "2004-05": "202575",
              "2005-06": "239683",
              "2006-07": "277286",
              "2007-08": "326547",
              "2008-09": "377346",
              "2009-10": "NA",
              "2010-11": "NA" }]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would recommend looking up tutorials on using regex

Comment: actually I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This is why looking up tutorials are the best way to go. Giving you the answer here won’t help you again in the future.

Comment: https://regex101.com   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about this kind of a problem in general, is:

1. I would first convert the object into an array of the relevant data. In this case `Object.entries` will serve our purpose well, it gives us an array of "tuples" (a tuple is just an array), where each tuple consists of 2 values, a KEY and its corresponding VALUE.
2. We can then filter the array of tuples, this is where we find out if the give value is a valid number. We do this by attempting to parse it as a number, and the interpreting that result as a boolean. The key thing to know here is that `Number("NA")` returns `NaN` (not a number), and `Boolean(NaN)` is false (worth noting, `Boolean(0)` is also false, so this method only works if you know for a fact that the numbers wont ever be equal to `0`).
3. Finally we can turn this filtered list of tuples back into an object, using `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const input = {
  "1999-00": "125236",
  "2000-01": "140119",
  "2001-02": "151482",
  "2002-03": "163385",
  "2003-04": "184463",
  "2004-05": "202575",
  "2005-06": "239683",
  "2006-07": "277286",
  "2007-08": "326547",
  "2008-09": "377346",
  "2009-10": "NA",
  "2010-11": "NA"
};

const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input)
    .filter(([k, v]) => 
      Boolean(Number(v))
    )
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `map` and inside that take entries of object and then filter the ones which do not match digit regex `/\d+/`. Something like this:

```js
var stateData=[ {"1999-00": "125236", "2000-01": "140119", "2001-02": "151482", "2002-03": "163385", "2003-04": "184463", "2004-05": "202575", "2005-06": "239683", "2006-07": "277286", "2007-08": "326547", "2008-09": "377346", "2009-10": "NA", "2010-11": "NA" }];

var result = stateData.map(p=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(p).filter(([k,v])=>v.match(/\d+/))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression `/^\d+$/` to check the string value has only numbers or not. If the value passes the regular expression, you can select it and ignore it if fails

```
let result = stateData.map(value => {
    const temp = {};
    for(var key in value) {
        if(/^\d+$/.test(value[key])
         temp[key] = value[key]
    }
    return temp;
}

//result array will have all the values which are numbers
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (use `/^\d+$/` to test if it's all numerical):

```js
const stateData = [{
  "1999-00": "125236",
  "2000-01": "140119",
  "2001-02": "151482",
  "2002-03": "163385",
  "2003-04": "184463",
  "2004-05": "202575",
  "2005-06": "239683",
  "2006-07": "277286",
  "2007-08": "326547",
  "2008-09": "377346",
  "2009-10": "NA",
  "2010-11": "NA3"
}]


console.log(stateData.map(
  x =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).filter(([_, val]) => /^\d+$/.test(val)))
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can is `isNaN()` to check whether the value is number or not.

```js
var stateData = [{
  "1999-00": "125236",
  "2000-01": "140119",
  "2001-02": "151482",
  "2002-03": "163385",
  "2003-04": "184463",
  "2004-05": "202575",
  "2005-06": "239683",
  "2006-07": "277286",
  "2007-08": "326547",
  "2008-09": "377346",
  "2009-10": "NA",
  "2010-11": "NA"
}]
var result = stateData.map(p=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(p).filter(([k,v])=> !(isNaN(v)))));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as short as it gets, do try

```js
let stateData=[{"1999-00": "125236",
                "2000-01": "140119",
                "2001-02": "151482",
                "2002-03": "163385",
              "2003-04": "184463",
              "2004-05": "202575",
              "2005-06": "239683",
              "2006-07": "277286",
              "2007-08": "326547",
              "2008-09": "377346",
              "2009-10": "NA",
              "2010-11": "NA"}]

let result = []

for(let key in stateData[0]) {
  if(+stateData[0][key]) {
    result.push(stateData[0][key])
  }
}


console.log(result)
```